# Passing props via react-router-dom useNavigate (navigate) is failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `"react-router-dom": "^6.15.0"` and for some reason I am unable to pass props from componentA to ComponentB.

I am using this code within my component A:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function ComponentA() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    navigate('/new', { state: { myid: id, mypath: 'Home' } });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>ComponentB</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then in my ComponentB, I have this code:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function ComponentB() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { myid, mypath } = location.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>mypath: {mypath}</p>
      <p>mypath: {mypath}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ComponentB;
```

As soon as I run my code and call ComponentB, the app crashes saying that:

```
Cannot destructure property 'myid' of 'location.state' as it is null.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'mypath' of 'location.state' as it is null.
```

Unfortunately I can't see what I am missing or doing wrong as the state props are NOT being carried over to `ComponentB`.

Comment: Could you [edit] to clarify the reproduction steps and to share a more complete [mcve] for where and how these two components are rendered? What do you mean "call ComponentB"? Perhaps even create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese To explain the flow, I am in ComponentA where there is a button for the user to press that will navigate to the route `/new` that navigates to  ComponentB. On pressing this button, I need to pass the info of `myid` and `mypath` over to CpmponentB. Now once in componentB, I simply need to access both myid and mypath by using useLocation and inturn location.state, these props don't exist or even come across. Unfortunately I am not able to create a codesandbox. I have googled this and found what I am doing seems to be the correct approach. Any ideas pls?

Comment: You can't make a sandbox demo because you can't reproduce the issue in it, or something else? What are the values you are trying to pass in route state? `mypath` is obviously a string, but what about `id`, what is that?

Comment: The `id` is just a number of the record the user is viewing. Do you think that there could be an issue with the actual data?

Comment: The values you pass through route state ***must*** be JSON serializable. If they are not this is certainly a cause for the state to be nullified. If you reload the page while rendering `ComponentB`, this too could remove the route state. I'm afraid that without a complete [mcve] or a running sandbox we can really only speculate as to why the state is null. If you pull `myid` out of the route state does it all work as expected, i.e. have defined state and not crash?

Comment: Here's a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-props-via-react-router-dom-usenavigate-navigate-is-failing-z8rvp6) with your code copy/pasted and it works as I'd expect. I can navigate to `"/new"` and see the passed state values. Maybe try killing the development server and processes, and restart the local build and try again.

Comment: I removed the myid and now just have: `navigate('/new', { state: { mypath: 'Home' } });` and the console.log of location is: {
    "pathname": "/new",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "state": null,
    "key": "default"
} So `state` is null

Comment: @DrewReese - the only difference I have to your codesandbox is that my components are in there own individual files. I just can't work it out and unsure what other means I can get this info over to the other component.

Comment: You might try deleting the `node_modules` directory and rerunning `npm install` to reinstall all your dependencies, and restart your app. Outside this, just about 100% of the time I've seen someone with the same issue on a new project they've reported back that using `create-reacte-app` and recreating the project and re-installing `react-router-dom` everything worked.